# # symbol messing up SQL queries

Tags: mysql, sql

I must use a SQL SELECT statement to return some results. I need to return two pieces of information regarding employees, the Employee# and EmployeeName.

I've tried

```
SELECT Employee#, EmployeeName FROM EmployeeTable
```

But in MySQL everything from the # symbol forward is greyed out. That symbol is messing up my query but it's a part of the table given me. How do I search using this Employee# without it getting messed up? Thank you.

Comment: This for MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: This is why naming columns with junk like `#` in them is usually a bad idea.

Comment: Your question indicates MySQL but your tags indicate sql-server (implying Microsoft). Which is it? If it were MSSQL you could put the name in brackets [Employee#] though I don't even know that it would be allowed

Comment: It's definitely MySql, because the engine is treating the # symbol as a comment indicator. Sql Server would not do that.

Answer (score 5):

Use backticks (`) to escape weird column and table names in MySQL:

```
SELECT `Employee#`, EmployeeName FROM EmployeeTable
```

Or, even better, don't use special characters in those names in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

For MySQL:

```
SELECT `Employee#`, EmployeeName FROM EmployeeTable
```

For SQL Server:

```
SELECT [Employee#], [EmployeeName] FROM [EmployeeTable]
```

It's the same idea, but MySQL has a different delimiter for escaping table names.

Comment: Thanks man! Idk why I never thought to even try that lol Can I then reference it as 'Employee#'.EmployeeTable for use in joins etc? Also, I tried to upvote you but I'm new and it says I need reputation to upvote...any way around that to give you credit? Thanks

Comment: @user2788882 Becareful: you used single quotes in your comment, but you need to use backticks for this to work. If you are using backticks, you can use them for joins and any other places table and columns names are used.

Comment: Same idea: `[EmployeeTable].[Employee#]` vs `\`EmployeeTable\`.\`Employee#\``.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT [Employee#], EmployeeName FROM EmployeeTable

Answer (score 0):

The ANSI SQL compliant way to escape column names is to enclose column names in double qoutes .
This works across all ANSI compliant DBMS - MySQL ,SQL Server,Oracle etc.

For MySQL , you can use backticks or enable [ANSI SQL mode](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/compatibility.html) after which

```
SELECT "Employee#", EmployeeName FROM EmployeeTable
```